# How to trigger child process code from another file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process

I have code basically like this in one file, index.js:

```
module.exports = {
    const processHandler = require("myOtherFile.js");
    cp = require("child_process");
    cp.fork(pathOfCodeForFork);
    cp.send("message");
}
```

In another file (myOtherFile.js) I have:

```
process.on("message", function(msg) {
    console.log("here is the message " + msg);
}
```

The file loads but the code inside the process.on block never executes. Would really appreciate some guidance. New to child processes and probably not setting this up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

So I asked this question, but I figured out the issue and wanted to post for anyone else struggling with this (and ask a follow-up). It turns out that pulling out the require for the myOtherFile.js from the module causes this to work (so, place  const processHandler = require("myOtherFile.js"); above the module code altogether). The follow up, is I am not sure why? Is the reference to process different inside and outside the module? Or is this a circular requires issue somehow? Is this about the order in which things get run? Something else?